# Goroutine seem to defy the lock added into a function defined in another package

Tags: go, locking, mutex, goroutine

It looks like I am missing something when trying to use lock in go.

In the following method named `Write`, I call the `Lock` function at the start and `Unlock` just before the return statement.

```
type DiskConfiguration struct {
    M sync.Mutex
}

func (dc *DiskConfiguration) Write(fileName string, b []byte) error {
    dc.M.Lock()
    if dc.Exists(fileName) {
        return errors.New(RecordAlreadyExists)
    }
    gr := bytes.Fields(debug.Stack())[1]
    
    // Print goroutine id
    fmt.Println("CORE WRITE FUNC ", fileName, "   ", string(gr))

    err := os.WriteFile(fileName, b, DefaultFilePermission)
    dc.M.Unlock()
    return err
}
```

But this does not seem to work correctly when multiple goroutine (2 for my example) calls  this function from another package. The print logs from the above function looks as :

```
CORE WRITE FUNC  /PK/64e47b76147b359d7de3d41cee17d0d8.json     12
CORE WRITE FUNC  /PK/64e47b76147b359d7de3d41cee17d0d8.json     11
CORE WRITE FUNC  /PK/c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c.json     12
CORE WRITE FUNC  /PK/c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c.json     11
```

As you could see, different go-routines are simultaneously able to execute the statements inside `Write` function.

What am I missing here?

A snapshot of the inside of goroutine looks as :

```
        // Inside the goroutine
        _, cErr := model.Create(api.Create{
            Values: testRecord.Data[i],
        })
```

The above `model.Create` internally calls the above `Write` function.

This is what `Create` looks like:

```
func (m Model) Create(c Create) (structs.CreateDataMap, error) {
    if !utilities.IsEmptyString(m.Name) && !utilities.IsNil(m.Schema) {
        dataMap := m.MapParams(&c)
        document := core.InitDocument(m.root)
        writeErr := document.Write(m.Name, m.Schema, &dataMap)
        if writeErr != nil {
            return nil, writeErr
        }
        return dataMap, nil
    } else {
        panic(SchemaNotInitialized)
    }
}
```

From within the `Create` function a call to `Write` is made , which calls the `Write` func on `Disk` struct.

This is what the `document.Write` method looks like:

```
func (d *Document) Write(schemaName string, schema structs.Schema, dataMap *structs.CreateDataMap) error {
    pk, fPK := parser.ExtractPrimaryKey(schema)
    dbUtil := DBUtil()
    pkValue := dbUtil.GenerateUUID()
    pkName := parser.DefaultPrimaryKey
    if fPK {
        pkName = pk
        // Since the values inside the data map could be of any type
        // it is important to detect the type and based on that
        // return the value after the type cast
        pkValue = extractPKWithCorrectType((*dataMap)[pkName])
    } else {
        // Update the data map with the system generated primary key
        (*dataMap)[pkName] = pkValue
    }

    // Generate the directory if it does not exist
    disk := InitDiskConfiguration(d.root)
    // Create the directory for primary keys
    // If the directory already exists, the directory
    // will not be recreated
    directory := PathJoiner(true, d.root, schemaName, dbUtil.GetPrimaryKeyRoot())
    _, dErr := disk.CreateDirectoryChain(directory)
    // Once the directory to store the primary keys has been created
    // we need to calculate the hash of the primary key. The hash
    // will be the name of the document that will be stored
    // inside the primary key directory
    if dErr != nil {
        panic(dErr)
    }
    primaryKeyHash := dbUtil.GeneratePrimaryKeyHash(pkValue)
    dataBytes := []byte(utilities.Stringify(*dataMap))
    recordPath := PathJoiner(false, directory, primaryKeyHash+".json")

    // THE MAIN WRITE METHOD, THAT HOLDS THE MUTEX
    writeErr := disk.Write(recordPath, dataBytes)
    if writeErr != nil {
        if writeErr.Error() == RecordAlreadyExists {
            return errors.New(PrimaryKeyConstraintViolated + " (" + pkName + ")")
        }
        // Failed to create the record
        return writeErr
    }

    return nil
}
```

Also, this is where the `DiskConfiguration` gets initialized (called from the above method:

```
func InitDiskConfiguration(root string) *DiskConfiguration {
    err := os.Mkdir(root, DefaultDirectoryPermission)
    if err != nil && !os.IsExist(err) {
        // Creation of the root directory is a must before proceeding
        panic(err)
    }
    return &DiskConfiguration{}
}
```

For anyone interested (and if this helps), this is how the `goroutine` looks like:

```
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var m sync.Mutex

    f := func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
            _, cErr := model.Create(api.Create{
                Values: testRecord.Data[i],
            })

            if cErr == nil {
                m.Lock()
                totalRecordsCreated += 1
                m.Unlock()
            }
        }

    }

    wg.Add(1)
    go f()
    wg.Add(1)
    go f()
    wg.Wait()
    // assert.Equal(t, 2, totalRecordsCreated, "Should be able to handle concurrent writes")
```

Comment: Note that you are not unlocking the mutex when returning an error (the dc.Exists case). Use `defer dc.M.Unlock()` right below `dc.M.Lock()` to ensure that the mutex gets always unlocked, even in case of `panic`.

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks. Any idea, why would in spite of locking, different goroutines are able to execute the statements?

Comment: @mkopriva. Updating.

Comment: You should never export your mutexes (by starting the variable with a capital). They're meant for critical sections and you don't want code from other packages interfering with your mutexes

Comment: @mkopriva Updated. I have tried to share the main flow, which ultimately leads to the `Write` call on `Disk`. If you are not satisfied with this, I can share more function and struct details.

Comment: @mkopriva Added code for goroutine too.

Comment: @SuhailGupta Maybe I'm mistaken but it looks like you are creating a new `DiskConfiguration` for each goroutine. If that is the case then that's going to definitely behave the way you describe. If you have two DCs then you have two Mutexes, locking one will not lock the other.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes, that is a big mistake. What would you recommend here?

Comment: Instead of a field use an unexported variable declared at the top-level (package-level). E.g. declare `var dcMu sync.Mutex` just above the `Write` method. Make sure that any code within the package that needs to "respect" the lock uses that variable, and uses it properly (has a matching unlock for every lock). This is a common pattern in the stdlib.

Comment: example https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/testing/benchmark.go#L69

Comment: @mkopriva Thanks again.  Would you want to post an answer, or should I do it?

Comment: Feel free to do it yourself. I'm too lazy to write up a nice useful answer.